# How would I reconfigure a super complicated ternary statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, conditional-operator

So I'm trying to render an image based on certain boolean values. It works for now with this ternary statement but there's going to be much more options and I was wondering if there's a better way of writing this.

Here is the ternary statement:

```
<img id="car" alt="" height="200" width="500" src={this.state.isRed && this.state.rimOne ? "/Assets/red.png" : this.state.isRed && this.state.rimTwo ? "/Assets/red2.png" : this.state.isBlue && this.state.rimOne ? "/Assets/Blue.png" : this.state.isBlue && this.state.rimTwo ? "/Assets/Blue2.png" : this.state.isLightBlue && this.state.rimOne ? "/Assets/lightblue.png" : this.state.isLightBlue && this.state.rimTwo ? "/Assets/lightblue2.png" : this.state.isSkyBlue && this.state.rimOne ? "/Assets/Skyblue.png" : this.state.isSkyBlue && this.state.rimTwo ? "/Assets/Skyblue2.png" : this.state.isWhite && this.state.rimOne ? "/Assets/White.png" : this.state.isWhite && this.state.rimTwo ? "/Assets/white2.png" : null}></img>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use an `if-else` statement from your JavaScript to compute the value for `src`, then use this value in your HTML/view code:

```
var src = null;
if (this.state.isRed && this.state.rimOne) {
    src = "/Assets/red.png";
}
else if (this.state.isRed && this.state.rimTwo) {
    src = "/Assets/red2.png";
}
else if (this.state.isBlue && this.state.rimOne) {
    src = "/Assets/Blue.png";
}
else if (this.state.isBlue && this.state.rimTwo) {
    src = "/Assets/Blue2.png";
}
else if (this.state.isLightBlue && this.state.rimOne) {
    src = "/Assets/lightblue.png";
}
else if (this.state.isLightBlue && this.state.rimTwo) {
    src = "/Assets/lightblue2.png";
}
else if (this.state.isSkyBlue && this.state.rimOne) {
    src = "/Assets/Skyblue.png";
}
else if (this.state.isSkyBlue && this.state.rimTwo) {
    src = "/Assets/Skyblue2.png";
}
else if (this.state.isWhite && this.state.rimOne) {
    src = "/Assets/White.png";
}
else if (this.state.isWhite && this.state.rimTwo) {
    src = "/Assets/white2.png";
}
```

Comment: And finally, of course, `document.getElementById("car").src = src`. (Just for completeness, and because I like to explain stuff to people like they're 5, apparently.)

Answer (score 3):

It is equivalent to

```
if (<img id="car" alt="" height="200" width="500" src={this.state.isRed && this.state.rimOne) {
    "/Assets/red.png"
} else {
    if (this.state.isRed && this.state.rimTwo) {
        "/Assets/red2.png"
    } else {
        if (this.state.isBlue && this.state.rimOne) {
            "/Assets/Blue.png"
        } else {
                    if (this.state.isBlue && this.state.rimTwo) {
                "/Assets/Blue2.png"
            } else {
                        if (this.state.isLightBlue && this.state.rimOne) {
                    "/Assets/lightblue.png"
                } else {
                                    if (this.state.isLightBlue && this.state.rimTwo) {
                        "/Assets/lightblue2.png"
                    } else {
                                        if (this.state.isSkyBlue && this.state.rimOne) {
                            "/Assets/Skyblue.png"
                        } else {
                                                    if (this.state.isSkyBlue && this.state.rimTwo) {
                                "/Assets/Skyblue2.png"
                            } else {
                                                        if (this.state.isWhite && this.state.rimOne) {
                                    "/Assets/White.png"
                                } else {
                                                                    if (this.state.isWhite && this.state.rimTwo) {
                                        "/Assets/white2.png"
                                    } else {
                                        null}></img>
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Better to use switch case

Answer (score 2):

I did some codegolfing to come up with this:

```js
function getAssetURL() {
  if (!this.state.rimOne && !this.state.rimTwo)
    return null;
  let s = '/Assets/';
  ['Red', 'Blue', 'LightBlue', 'SkyBlue', 'White'].forEach(c => this.state['is' + c] && (s += c));
  return (s + (this.state.rimTwo ? '2' : '') + '.png').replace(/[RL]|\wB|W.*2/g, l => l.toLowerCase());
}
```

Here is a demonstration that it produces identical results as another more verbose answer:

```js
'use strict';

const object = {};

['isRed', 'isBlue', 'isLightBlue', 'isSkyBlue', 'isWhite'].forEach(color => {
  ['rimOne', 'rimTwo'].forEach(number => {
    const state = { [color]: true, [number]: true };
    object.state = state;
    console.log(color, number);
    console.log(' ' + getAssetURL1.call(object));
    console.log(' ' + getAssetURL2.call(object));
  });
});

function getAssetURL1() {
  if (!this.state.rimOne && !this.state.rimTwo)
    return null;
  let s = '/Assets/';
  ['Red', 'Blue', 'LightBlue', 'SkyBlue', 'White'].forEach(c => this.state['is' + c] && (s += c));
  return (s + (this.state.rimTwo ? '2' : '') + '.png').replace(/[RL]|\wB|W.*2/g, l => l.toLowerCase());
}

function getAssetURL2() {
  var src = null;
  if (this.state.isRed && this.state.rimOne) {
    src = "/Assets/red.png";
  }
  else if (this.state.isRed && this.state.rimTwo) {
    src = "/Assets/red2.png";
  }
  else if (this.state.isBlue && this.state.rimOne) {
    src = "/Assets/Blue.png";
  }
  else if (this.state.isBlue && this.state.rimTwo) {
    src = "/Assets/Blue2.png";
  }
  else if (this.state.isLightBlue && this.state.rimOne) {
    src = "/Assets/lightblue.png";
  }
  else if (this.state.isLightBlue && this.state.rimTwo) {
    src = "/Assets/lightblue2.png";
  }
  else if (this.state.isSkyBlue && this.state.rimOne) {
    src = "/Assets/Skyblue.png";
  }
  else if (this.state.isSkyBlue && this.state.rimTwo) {
    src = "/Assets/Skyblue2.png";
  }
  else if (this.state.isWhite && this.state.rimOne) {
    src = "/Assets/White.png";
  }
  else if (this.state.isWhite && this.state.rimTwo) {
    src = "/Assets/white2.png";
  }
  return src;
}
```